# Cross entopy question for semantic segmentation procedure

Tags: semantic-segmentation, cross-entropy

How to use cross entropy for float images and labels?
I'm studying Semantic segmentation with Cityscapes data.

When I use

```
torchivision.transfrom.ToTensor()
```

My Images and labels data are transform the range from [0~255] to [0~1]. Because I used ToTensor().

Then I passed images to a model, I got prediction (Batch X class X W X H) from.

After that, I want to use CrossEntropy to get loss.
The labels is (Batch X W X H), range [0~1]
The prediction is (Batch X Class X W X H), range[-inf ~ +inf (somewhere)]

But I got an error, Those input should be Tensor.long.

**If I cast theos labels to Tensor.Long, labels should be all 0.**

What shoud I do???

The cityscapes should be treated ignore index.
Cross entropy has Ignore index.
But the labels are [0~1] range.

Answer (score 0):

Solve by myself.
In Segmentation, No use Normalize and toTensor.

Thanks.